# How to set content-type in a POST request in R?

Tags: r, web-services, curl, rcurl

I have to make a post request. The problem is, the application that is exposing it's api as webservice, has set it's Content-Type to "text/plain". I tried RCurl package and httpRequest package but could not figure out how to set the content-type. I tried to directly make a postrequest to a URL that did not have that content-type, then postForm worked. Any help here?

EDIT: I will try to explain what I need to do here. I have an url. I need to make POST requests to it by passing it some parameters something like this

```
POST to "url/agents/where/agent?="Smith"
```

This is what you would type if you use the REST console extension on chrome for making webservice calls. I need to make this from R by setting the content-type to "text/plain"

What I have tried is this,

```
postForm("url/agents/get/all")
```

This works like a charm as say in our case the webservice call for calling all the agents does not require the content-type to be "text/plain" and also does not require any parameters to be passed to it(eg. no particular agent name as I want all of them). I think I have figured out how to pass a parameter by giving name value pairs in a list to .opts. What I am not able to figure out is how to set content-type.

I have tried this but it failed,

```
postForm("url/agents/where",
         .opts = list(postfields = toJSON(list("name" = "Smith")),
         httpheader = c('Content-Type' = 'text/plain', ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful to have the code that you've tried, but the general answer is that you can specify it in the `httpheader` argument to `curlPerform`. Here's a slightly modified version from [the documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RCurl/docs/curlPerform):

```
h <- basicTextGatherer()
h$reset()
curlPerform(url,
            httpheader=c('Content-Type' = "text/plain"),
            postfields=toJSON(list("name" = "Smith")),
            customrequest = 'POST', 
            writefunction = h$update,
            verbose = TRUE,
            ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
body <- h$value()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I am sorry but due to my company policy, I won't be able to share the actual code and url I am trying to hit. And as the exposing as webservice was done by some other team, I am not able to generate a simple example. I will try your answer and get back to you.

Comment: @Avinash Well, you can leave out the url, I mainly just what commands have you used and what arguments are you trying to pass. See my edit, I forgot the first line from the example.

Comment: curlPerform is trying to make a GET request from it. I need to make a POST request. I will try to explain what I have done in the question.

Comment: @Avinash See my edit. You need to put `ssl.verifypeer` outside of the `httpheader` argument. And you specify a POST request specifically.

Comment: Where does the postfields paranthesis end?

Comment: Yeah. It works. Thanks a ton. I am going to upvote all your comments. I think the documentation for this package can be improved. It is not very intuitive for beginners.